# Cross-Origin Request Blocked (Ionic + Django)

Tags: django, angular, ionic-framework

I am building an application using ionic framework with backend written in Django.

When i try to do testing i am getting the following error message

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/api/.
>   (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

I saw some documentation and it was mentioned that i need to add proxies under ionic.config.json so i added the proxies it look something like this

```
"proxies":[
    {
      "path":"/api",
      "proxyUrl": "http://localhost:8000/api"
    }   
]
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You need to install [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) package, for handling the server headers required for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing

Comment: When i add this package i am getting this error. Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Comment: Add this line to your settings `CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True`, Also make sure you have added `CorsMiddleware` as high as possible, especially before any middleware that can generate responses such as Django's `CommonMiddleware`

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library

```
pip install django-cors-headers
```

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

Comment: When i add this package i am getting this error. Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)